# How to show that $\bigl(A(x) \land B(x) \bigr)\land C(x) \equiv A(x) \land \bigl(B(x)\land C(x) \bigr)?$

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-writing, first-order-logic, semigroups

Suppose $A(x),B(x),C(x)$ are statements. (For the purpose of my question, we don't need to specify what exactly they are)

How to show that $\bigl(A(x) \land B(x) \bigr)\land C(x)$  is equivalent to $A(x) \land \bigl(B(x)\land C(x)  \bigr)?$

Surefire way to do so would be to generate truth table, yet I would like to find more concise way to prove that.

This is what I've tried:

> Let's denote statement $\bigl(A(x) \land B(x)
>  \bigr)\land C(x)$ as $(1)$ and statement $A(x) \land \bigl(B(x)\land
>  C(x)  \bigr)$ as $(2)$
>
> Required to prove that $(1) \iff (2)$
>
> $(\rightarrow)$ Let x be some value such that $(1)$ is **true** and $(2)$ is
>   **false**. Since $(1)$ is true, all statements must be true, but for $(2)$ to be false, at least one statement must be false. Hence if
>    $(1)$ is true, then $(2)$ is true.
>
> $(\leftarrow)$ Suppose $(2)$ is **true**. Suppose $(1)$ is **false**. Since $(2)$ is true, it follows that all statements are true, but for $(1)$ to be false, at least one statement must be false, hence contradiction. In other words, if $(2)$ is true, then $(1)$ is true.
>
> Therefore, $(1) \iff (2)$ and thus $(1) \equiv (2)$. $\Box$

Is it correct? Are there better (and shorter) alternatives to prove the conjecture above?

Comment: this looks good to me

Comment: In the end, it is only an issue of propositional logic : thus an argument based only on truth values will suffice.

Comment: Perhaps the [tag:semigroups] tag be appropriate here. After all, you're trying to establish associativity.

Comment: I'd use the [method of analytic tableaux](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux).

Comment: I'd like to encourage you to undelete your post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3309660/prove-that-if-n-is-divisible-by-2-and-3-then-n-is-divisible-by-6; apparently I'm not the only person who feels this way--there are at least two undelete votes!  Cheers!

Comment: @RobetLewis Undeleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to various metaproperties of propositional logic together with, say, [this natural deduction calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Example_2._Natural_deduction_system), we can equivalently show the logical equivalence by showing derivability in both directions.

Formally:

> **Corollary**: We have $(A(x) ∧ B(x)) ∧ C(x) ≡ A(x) ∧ (B(x) ∧ C(x))$ iff.
>
> 1. $(A(x) ∧ B(x)) ∧ C(x) \vdash A(x) ∧ (B(x) ∧ C(x))$
> 2. and $A(x) ∧ (B(x) ∧ C(x)) \vdash (A(x) ∧ B(x)) ∧ C(x)$.
>
> where $\equiv$ denotes logical equivalence with standard propositional logic and $\vdash$ denotes the [natural deduction calculus I linked above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Example_2._Natural_deduction_system).

*Proof:* I think completeness and soundness play important roles, but would need to look up precise definitions to be really sure.

> **Lemma:** 1. and 2. from above are in fact fulfilled.

*Proof:* For 1. we apply the introduction rule for conjunction and therefore have to show $A(x)$ and $B(x) \wedge C(x)$ separately. Applying the same rule for the latter conjunction we get in total three subgoals: $A(x)$, $B(x)$ and $C(x)$. We can easily extract them from our hypothesis (left of $\vdash$) by conjunction elimination.

Step 2. works similarly.

---

As a comment to your solution and the other answer: Personally, I developed the habit of always preferring constructive proofs over proofs involving proof-by-contradiction. Especially with proving with a calculus as done above, we can directly see where the evidence for our proof goals comes from!

Answer (score 0):

Assume $$A\land(B\land C)\tag{$P$}$$ and, for a contradiction, $$\lnot((A\land B)\land C).\tag{$Q$}$$

From $(P)$, we have $A$ and $B\land C$, the latter of which gives $B$ and $C$; now, from $(Q)$, we have *either* $\lnot(A\land B)$ *or* $\lnot C$, but since $C$, we must have the former, which, in turn, gives *either* $\lnot A$ *or* $\lnot B$, but both of which are impossible.

Thus $(P)\implies \lnot (Q)$.

Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a concise proof, note that false-is-$0$, true-is-$1$ reduces $\land$ to multiplication, which is famously associative.